# internal error in ANTLR4 grammar rules

Tags: antlr4

I wrote my own grammar:

```
grammar SimpleCode;

program: 'class Program' '{' field_decl* method_decl* '}' ;

field_decl: type id_int_list ;

id_int: id
      | id '[' int_literal ']'
      ;

id_int_list: id_int
           | id_int (',' id_int)*
           ;

method_decl: (type | 'void') id id_type_list? block ;

id_type_list: (type id)
            | (type id) (','(type id))*
            ;

block: '{' var_decl* statement* '}' ;

var_decl: type id_list ;

id_list: id
       | id (',' id)*
       ;

type: 'int'
    | 'boolean'
    ;

statement: location assign_op expr ';'
         | method_call ';'
         | 'if' expr block 'else' block
         | 'for' id '=' expr ',' expr block
         | 'return' expr? ';'
         | 'break' ';'
         | 'continue' ';'
         | block
         ;

assign_op: '='
         | '+='
         | '-='
         ;

method_call: method_name expr_list?
           | 'callout' (string_literal (',' callout_arg_list)?)
           ;

expr_list: expr
         | expr (',' expr)*
         ;

callout_arg_list: callout_arg
                | callout_arg (',' callout_arg)*
                ;

method_name: id ;

location: id
        | id '[' expr ']'
        ;

expr: location
    | method_call
    | literal
    | expr bin_op expr
    | '-' expr
    | '!' expr
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

callout_arg: expr
           | string_literal
           ;

bin_op: arith_op
      | rel_op
      | eq_op
      | cond_op
      ;

arith_op: '+'
        | '-'
        | '*'
        | '\\'
        | '%'
        ;

rel_op: '>'
      | '<'
      | '>='
      | '<='
      ;

eq_op: '=='
     | '!='
     ;

cond_op: '&&'
       | '||'
       ;

literal: int_literal
       | char_literal
       | bool_literal
       ;

id: alpha alpha_num* ;

alpha_num: alpha
         | digit
         ;

alpha: ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' ) ;

digit: '0'..'9' ;

hex_digit: digit
         | 'a'..'f'
         | 'A'..'F'
         ;

int_literal: decimal_literal
           | hex_literal
           ;

decimal_literal: digit digit* ;

hex_literal: '0x' hex_digit hex_digit* ;

bool_literal: 'true'
            | 'false'
            ;

char_literal: '\'' char '\'' ;


string_literal: '\"' char* '\"' ;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ ->skip ;
```

I got this error:

```
error(20): SimpleCode.g4:8:12: internal error: Rule int_literal undefined
```

I don't know why this error happened. The int_literal was defined. Please explain to me why this error happened. I didn't find out the reason.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code and the main problem is that you have not seperated the Parser rules from the Lexer rules. This is done using Capitals/Case sensitivity. Lexer rules are defined in caps. once this was corrected your grammar also had 1 more error in that the rule "char" was undefined.

here is an amended version:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

grammar SimpleCode;


program: 'class Program' '{' field_decl* method_decl* '}' ;

field_decl: type id_int_list ;

id_int: id
      | id '[' int_literal ']'
      ;

id_int_list: id_int
           | id_int (',' id_int)*
           ;

method_decl: (type | 'void') id id_type_list? block ;

id_type_list: (type id)
            | (type id) (','(type id))*
            ;

block: '{' var_decl* statement* '}' ;

var_decl: type id_list ;

id_list: id
       | id (',' id)*
       ;

type: 'int'
    | 'boolean'
    ;

statement: location assign_op expr ';'
         | method_call ';'
         | 'if' expr block 'else' block
         | 'for' id '=' expr ',' expr block
         | 'return' expr? ';'
         | 'break' ';'
         | 'continue' ';'
         | block
         ;

assign_op: '='
         | '+='
         | '-='
         ;

method_call: method_name expr_list?
           | 'callout' (string_literal (',' callout_arg_list)?)
           ;

expr_list: expr
         | expr (',' expr)*
         ;

callout_arg_list: callout_arg
                | callout_arg (',' callout_arg)*
                ;

method_name: id ;

location: id
        | id '[' expr ']'
        ;

expr: location
    | method_call
    | literal
    | expr bin_op expr
    | '-' expr
    | '!' expr
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

callout_arg: expr
           | string_literal
           ;

bin_op: arith_op
      | rel_op
      | eq_op
      | cond_op
      ;

arith_op: '+'
        | '-'
        | '*'
        | '\\'
        | '%'
        ;

rel_op: '>'
      | '<'
      | '>='
      | '<='
      ;

eq_op: '=='
     | '!='
     ;

cond_op: '&&'
       | '||'
       ;

literal: int_literal
       | char_literal
       | bool_literal
       ;

id: ALPHA alpha_num* ;

alpha_num: ALPHA
         | DIGIT
         ;

ALPHA: ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' ) ;

DIGIT: '0'..'9' ;

HEX_DIGIT: DIGIT
         | 'a'..'f'
         | 'A'..'F'
         ;

int_literal: decimal_literal
           | hex_literal
           ;

decimal_literal: DIGIT DIGIT* ;

hex_literal: '0x' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT* ;

bool_literal: 'true'
            | 'false'
            ;

char_literal: '\'' ALPHA '\'' ;


string_literal: '\"' ALPHA* '\"' ;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ ->skip ;
```

The lexer rules are used to create token streams and the parser for the semantics so distinguishing which rules are which is important in a combined grammar.

There is a good post on [this](https://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/203932-ANTLR-When-to-use-Parser-Rules-vs-Lexer-Rules) forum with a fairly detailed breakdown of exactly the difference and why its needed. But other than the missing rule and lack of lexer definition it was all good. Just remember INT : DIGIT+ ; // lexer rules in caps.

Good luck on your project!

Comment: Only the first letter must be upper case for a lexer rule, e.g. `Digit` is a valid lexer rule name.

Comment: True but whilst valid a lot of the grammars shared seem to conventionally to be entirely blocks to make it easier to tell them apart, but valid point :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot about lexer rules and parser rules. My bad at all.

Comment: Dont worry everyone does this sooner or later and encounters these errors using ANTLR and since theres no error even using ANTLRWORKs or another IDE wont pickup on the issue. Anyway good luck!